# What are the alternative ways of not exposing a field in the response for a nested DTO

Tags: java, oop

The situation I'm tackling is about a **DTO** that has several nested **DTOs** in it and I'm trying to exclude a field from one of them in the response that is returned to the user using REST API. To make the picture cleaner I'm going to give an example of my situation.
I have a **SampleDTO** that has a **SecondDTO** in it. The **SecondDTO** has a **ThirdDTO** in it but this DTO has a "secretMessage" field. I'm trying to exclude this field from the response that we get through parsing the **SampleDTO** to JSON. These are the things I tried:

- Applying **@JsonIgnore** annotation on the field - This was the optimal solution but in my project, I have a microservice architecture and some of the services use this **SampleDTO** through internal clients.
- Making two separate **DTOs** - **SampleDTO** - the one we return to the user without the field and **InternalSampleDTO** - the one we use for our internal service communication
- The upper point works well for **DTOs** that are not nested but in order to apply it for my **SampleDTO** I have to create several **InternalDTOs** because of the nesting situation

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: This sounds like [Jackson views](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) might be of help

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the constructor of DTOs.

I tried this once by having multiple constructors, I had more controller over it.